# ASP.NET - Implementing Search Functionality and SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, forms, search

I have created a form which the user can use in order to search for transactions.  This is a picture of the form:

[image]

Now, the **total price** drop down list has the members:

1. Any Price
2. Exact Amount
3. Below Amount
4. Above Amount

The **currency** drop down list has the members:

1. Any Currency
2. EUR
3. USD
4. GBP

The **transaction date** drop down list has the members:

1. Any Date
2. Exact Date
3. Below Date
4. Above Date

The **transaction status** drop down list has the members:

1. Any Status
2. Active
3. Expired
4. Paid

All the details are being fetched from a table called **Payments**.

Can someone please help me how I can go about to search in the Payments table?  Can I satisfy all the different possibilities using one SQL statement?  Or do I have to use multiple SQL statements?  Can someone please give me a template of an SQL statement that can be used to satisfy the different possibilities?  Please help since SQL is not my strongest point.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Modified code below to allow ranges (including unbounded ranges)

A stored proc can easily handle queries such as this, if I understand correctly. You can make the parameters optional simply by checking for `NULL`. If a parameter is `NULL`, don't query based on it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE schema.FindPayments
(
    @MinPrice double = NULL,
    @MaxPrice double = NULL,
    @Currency char(3) = NULL,
    @MinTranDate datetime = NULL,
    @MaxTranDate datetime = NULL,
    @TranStatus int = NULL
)
AS BEGIN

    SELECT      *
    FROM        Payments
    WHERE       (
                        @MinPrice IS NULL
                    OR  TotalPrice >= @MinPrice
                )
            OR  (
                        @MaxPrice IS NULL
                    OR  TotalPrice <= @MaxPrice
                )
            OR  (
                        @Currency IS NULL
                    OR  Currency = @Currency
                )
            OR  (
                        @MinTranDate IS NULL
                    OR  TranDate >= @MinTranDate
                )
            OR  (
                        @MaxTranDate IS NULL
                    OR  TranDate <= @MaxTranDate
                )
            OR  (
                        @TranStatus IS NULL
                    OR  TranStatus = @TranStatus
                )
END
```

You can now call this stored proc from code passing in either `DBNull.Value` for unspecified parameters or, because I've assigned `NULL` as the default for all paramters, you can just pass the selected parameters.

```
SqlCommand l_findPayments = new SqlCommand("FindPayments", new SqlConnection("..."));
l_findPayments.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

if ( l_totalPriceComparison == "Exact Amount" )
{
    findPayments.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MinPrice", l_price));
    findPayments.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MaxPrice", l_price));
}
else if ( l_totalPriceComparison == "Below Amount" )
    findPayments.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MaxPrice", l_price));
else if ( l_totalPriceComparison == "Above Amount" )
    findPayments.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MinPrice", l_price));
// "Any Price" will just leave the parameter
// blank, so it will not filter on price

// ... repeat for all params

SqlDataReader l_result = l_findPayments.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: This only works when the user selects "Exact Amount", "Exact Date" and any status other than "Any Status". If the user selects, for example, "Below Amount", this will fail to return accurate results.

Comment: @HardCode - You are correct. A simple modification will allow you to specify ranges. An exact value `N` would simply be in the range `N to N`. For something like "Any Status", you'd just leave the parameter blank (thus returning any status).

Answer (score 3):

Best solution would be dynamically assembling the SQL query string in the C# code, according to the fields entered in the search form.

Comment: I understand.  It didn't cross my mind.  That would be a good alternative.  Thanks :)

Comment: And don't forget to use SQL parameters to pass the values. That avoids problems like SQL injection attacks and apostrophes in the data.

Comment: Why dynamic query over parameterized stored proc? Stored procs are faster and signficantly more resistant to injection attacks.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Yes but how am I going to build the statement to satisfy all possibilities?  The user can leave out any details he wants, he does not have to fill every field.  That's where the challenge lies.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 If you have to create code on the SQL side AND create conditionals in the C# code, I fail to see where your solution is simpler and more readable. Just because you *can* do something, does not mean you *should*. Additionally, you take functionality out of  the source code and into the database. You have to remember there's code in the SQL side, which might not be under to version control (while C# code should). Also, the filters might change with timewhich enforces my last point. As for the injection, you can create dynamic SQL code that takes parameters.

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro - It is easy to accidentally introduce injection-vulnerable code when assembling dynamic SQL in C#. It is hard to do so on the DBMS (though "Making something idiot-proof just results in smarter idiots"). Details of how to query something should be in the data-layer. Making your view/business-layer dependent on the details of your data-layer's implementation seems like a "bad practice". Of course, each individual has their own approach and much depends on the context/circumstances...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is to use your DB column names as the text box/dropdown id's.  that way, you can utilize their ID property from the code behind and you can use a loop to build a query based on your needs.  Assuming that you have these build in an HTML table or some other structure that can be similarly looped...

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM payments ";
string field = "";
string value = "";
int parameter_count = 0;
foreach(HtmlTableRow row in table.Rows)
{ 
    foreach(Control c in row.Cells[1].Controls)
    {
        if (c is Textbox)
        {
             TextBox txt = c as TextBox;
             if (txt.Text.Length > 0)
             {
                 field = txt.ID;
                 value = txt.Text.Trim();
                 if (parameter_count == 0)
                 {
                     sql += string.Format(" WHERE {0}='{1}' ", field, value);
                     parameter_count++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     sql += string.Format(" AND {0}='{1}' ", field, value);
                     parameter_count++;
                 }
             }
        }
        else if (c is DropDownList)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = c as DropDownList;
             if (ddl.SelectedValue.Length > 0)
             {
                 field = ddl.ID;
                 value = ddl.SelectedValue.Trim();
                 if (parameter_count == 0)
                 {
                     sql += string.Format(" WHERE {0}='{1}' ", field, value);
                     parameter_count++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     sql += string.Format(" AND {0}='{1}' ", field, value);
                     parameter_count++;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Now, there is an obvious drawback to simply using the string.Format to build your query, mainly that you are open to SQL injections.  However, I would suggest throwing out the string.Format section as they were purely for the sake of the example so that you could see the moment where you can capture the fields/values you will need to build a properly parameterized query.  The more important piece of this is all of the logic that wraps around those statements.  It gives you the ability to exclude the blank fields, and make them not affect the query result unless they have a value.  Hope this helps!

Comment: So, how would you build an injection-attack-proof solution with dynamic column names?